# Pass Function as a parameter in ASP.NET Core MVC Blazor

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor

I am using Bootstrap 5 modal in my ASP.NET Core 6 project to show alert messages.

I want to generalize the code and use it in different `.razor` components of my ASP.NET Core MVC app.

Here is the code of my `message.razor` component:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">ALERT !</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Are You Sure You Want To Delete ?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" @onclick="Function" data-bs-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At `onclick` function I want to pass the delete function with parameter, like this

```
@onclick="(e => OnDelete(emp.TypeOfId))"
```

to the `message.razor` component from another `.razor` component.

```
<MessageComponent Function="OnDelete(emp.TypeOfId)"></MessageComponent>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `Action` parameter to the `MessageComponent` that will be called when the button is clicked:

```
<button @onclick="Function">Button</button>

@code {
    [Parameter] public Action Function { get; set; }
}
```

Then from the parent you can pass the parameter like this:

```
<MessageComponent Function="@(() => OnDelete(emp.TypeOfId))"></MessageComponent>
```

**Update:**

In Blazor it is preferred to use `EventCallback` instead of `Action` so the previous example can become:

Child component:

```
<button @onclick="DeleteClicked">Delete</button>

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback DeleteClicked { get; set; }
}
```

Parent component:

```
<MessageComponent DeleteClicked="@(() => OnDelete(emp.TypeOfId))"></MessageComponent>
```